# No such file or directory Exception while creating a zip file

Tags: java, exception, filenotfoundexception

I have a working java application that created a zip file of a given folder. This works just fine on my computer (running Ubuntu) the code is as such:

```
public static void zipDir(String zipFileName, String dir) throws Exception {
        File dirObj = new File(dir);
        ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFileName));
        addDir(dirObj, out,dir);
        out.close();
      }

public static void addDir(File dirObj, ZipOutputStream out,String startDir) throws IOException {
        File[] files = dirObj.listFiles();
        byte[] tmpBuf = new byte[1024];

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
          if (files[i].isDirectory()) {
            addDir(files[i], out,startDir);
            continue;
          }
          String filename=files[i].toString();
          filename=filename.substring(filename.indexOf(startDir)+startDir.length());

          FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(files[i].getAbsolutePath());
          out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(filename));
          int len;
          while ((len = in.read(tmpBuf)) > 0) {
            out.write(tmpBuf, 0, len);
          }
          out.closeEntry();
          in.close();
        }
      }
```

When i run this on a virtual machine (also running ubuntu) i get a file not found exception.
The directory is there and i have write access to it (i created a txt file using nano).
I have read on a SO question that the problem might be on the files to be ziped, but those files are not accessed at the time of the exception. These are read at the `addDir` method just after the line that throws the exception is executed.

any ideas?

tracktrace

```
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:101)
        at ckan.upload.GetUploadFiles.zipDir(GetUploadFiles.java:347)
        at ckan.upload.GetUploadFiles.main(GetUploadFiles.java:110)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
```

This:

```
File zipFile = new File(zipFileName); 
System.out.println(zipFile.exists()); 
System.out.println(zipFile.isFile()); 
System.out.println(zipFile.canRead()); 
System.out.println(zipFile.canWrite());
```

returns FALSE for all 4 of them

Comment: Can you give us the stacktrace. Howdo you access the virtual machine and how do you run your java application?

Comment: btw. ``out.close();`` should be in a finally block

Comment: You can try locate problem through strace utility. Execute: `strace -e trace=file java ....option...`

Comment: @Würgspaß I am not sure how to get the stacktrace. The vm gets the git and execute the programm using an exexutable jar.

Comment: @SkarosIlias If you dont have a stacktrace, how come you know that the exception occurs prior to calling `addDir`? What error output do you actaully have? How does git execute the jar?

Comment: @Würgspaß, is this edit enough? What do you mean how git execute the jar? on the VM i pull the git and then i manually execute the jar.

Comment: For debuging add this to `zipDir`method and see what happens:
  `File zipFile = new File(zipFileName);
  System.out.println(zipFile.exists());
  System.out.println(zipFile.isFile());
  System.out.println(zipFile.canRead());
  System.out.println(zipFile.canWrite());`

Comment: @Würgspaß see updated question

Comment: could it comes from the filename itself? like using abstract instead of absolute or vice versa

Comment: @XioRcaL I was thinking the same thing! I was doing some testng and it seems that i couldnt read most of my files on the VM. I am working on that idea now